# How to use multiprocessing for parsing and processing large XML files?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, elementtree

I have a large XML file with newspaper articles and I want to tokenize these articles efficiently by using multiprocessing.

The XML file is very simple and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<corpus>
    <text id="1">
        <body>
            <title>Some headline words</title>
            <p>A sentence. Another sentence.</p>
            <p>Third sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
    <text id="2">
        <body>
            <title>Some other headline words</title>
            <p>A stupid sentence. Another stupid sentence.</p>
            <p>Third stupid sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
    ...
</corpus>
```

So far I parse the file using `iterparse` from `ElementTree`. However, because the task is so embarrassingly parallel I thought about using multiprocessing additionally. So I want to keep the low memory consumption benefits of `iterparse`, but want to split up the processing of the text elements to multiple processors. Order doesn't matter for me.

I tried it with the following code, but it exits with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`:

```py
def text_to_tokens(text_elem):
    text_id = text_elem.get("id")

    tokens = [tokenize(elem.text) for elem in text_elem.find("./body")]

    with open(f"{text_id}.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(tokens))

def tokenize(string):
    return string.split(" ")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:

        context = iter(ET.iterparse("corpus_file.xml", events=("start", "end")))
        event, root = next(context)

        for event, elem in context:
            if event == "end" and elem.tag == "text":
                pool.map(text_to_tokens, elem)
                root.clear()
```

How can I get multiprocessing to work? Any other hints or methods are much appreciated, I just want to parallelize this task and make it as fast as possible.

The full exit code looks like this:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "stack_overflow_test.py", line 15, in text_to_tokens
    tokens = [tokenize(elem.text) for elem in text_elem]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack_overflow_test.py", line 30, in <module>
    pool.map(text_to_tokens, elem)
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/daniel/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: What is `tokenize`? .. Please provide [mcve]. If we cannot copy from your question and test, we're less likely to help.

Comment: @wwii I'm sorry for the incompleteness of my question. I've added now the complete Traceback and a minimal tokenizer to my question.

Comment: Using your example xml, I do not get that exception.  I do get a `None.txt` file  with one line - `[]`.

Comment: @wwii Oh, my bad! I simplified my XML a little and did not test it again, sorry! Edited the XML and one line of my code with the original structure und it produces now the Exception above...

Comment: But it's strange that without the `body` element `text_id` resolves to `None` - I removed the `body` element of an XML sample with only three `text` elements (and the `.find("./body")`) for a little test, printed the `text_id` in `text_to_tokens` and got nine lines of `None`.

Comment: Do all the `text` elements have `body` elements?

Comment: @wwii Yes, they do. I extended the XML sample to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate token extraction and file creation. Use `concurrent.futures` to handle the concurrent details.

Change `text_to_tokens` to account for `body` element **and** return data instead of creating file.

```
def text_to_tokens(text_elem):
    text_id = text_elem.get("id")
    fname = f"{text_id}.txt"
    tokens = []
    for elem in text_elem.iter():
        if elem.tag in ('text','body'):
            continue
        tokens.append(tokenize(elem.text))
    return fname,tokens
```

New function to create a file.

```
def write(fname, data):
    with open(fname,'w') as f:
        f.write(str(data))
```

Extract the tokens in separate processes and write files in threads.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    context = iter(ET.iterparse(f, events=("start", "end")))
    event, root = next(context)
    token_futures = []
    write_futures = []
    with ProcPoolExc() as ppe, ThreadPoolExc() as tpe:
        for event, elem in context:
            if event == "end" and elem.tag == "text":
                token_futures.append(ppe.submit(text_to_tokens, elem))
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(token_futures):
            fname,data = future.result()
            write_futures.append(tpe.submit(write, *(fname,data)))
    for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(write_futures):
        e = fut.exception()
        print('success' if not e else e)
```

---

setup:

```
import concurrent.futures, io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ProcPoolExc = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor
ThreadPoolExc = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

s = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<corpus>
    <text id="1">
        <body>
            <title>Some headline words</title>
            <p>A sentence. Another sentence.</p>
            <p>Third sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
    <text id="2">
        <body>
            <title>Some other headline words</title>
            <p>A stupid sentence. Another stupid sentence.</p>
            <p>Third stupid sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
    <text id="3">
        <body>
            <title>Some other headline words</title>
            <p>A stupid sentence. Another stupid sentence.</p>
            <p>Third stupid sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
    <text id="4">
        <body>
            <title>Some other headline words</title>
            <p>A stupid sentence. Another stupid sentence.</p>
            <p>Third stupid sentence.</p>
        </body>
    </text>
</corpus>'''

f = io.StringIO(s)

def tokenize(string):
    return string.split(" ")
```

Comment: Is there any advantage in using `context = iter(ET.iterparse(f, events=("start", "end")))` instead of directly `context = ET.iterparse(f, events=("start", "end"))`? I know that line is just taken from the code in the question but I was wondering whether calling `iter` there has any point.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't think so, it works either way - `iterparse` is supposed to parse without loading the whole file - guess I should have asked why it was used.

Comment: @wwii Great, thank you so much! Is there a reason, that I should use `for elem in text_elem.iter():`... instead of `for elem in text_elem.find("./body")`? And is it still safe to do `root.clear()` after `token_futures.append(ppe.submit(text_to_tokens, elem))`? It seemed to work just fine, but maybe I'm missing some point...

Comment: @MartinHonnen No, `iter` has no special reason. Guess I borrowed this line of code somewhere when I started learning to work with XML and never changed it since then, because it worked...

Comment: @MartinHonnen - why are you  clearing`root`?- it woks if you include that. I used `elem.iter()` because it worked - it also works with the xpath, `.find("./body")`. AND the file creation works if it is in  `text_to_tokens`  using `concurrent.futures` - i was getting weird results with multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try this code without `with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:`?

Does it work?

If no, the issue lies outside of how you are using multiprocessing.

If yes, try to complete the initialization of your iterator before creating the pool. ie: place the below before initializing your pool.

```py
    context = iter(ET.iterparse("corpus_file.xml", events=("start", "end")))
    event, root = next(context)
```

Multiprocessing pickles objects, so it might not get passed through correctly if initialized after the pool is created.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it makes no difference. It still exits with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`...